# What is the mathematician's way of assigning a probability distribution to a range of number?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have an interval from 6 to 12. The probability of 6 = 1 and of 12 = 0. How to assign a probability to any other float that lies in the continuous interval between the two numbers. The closer to 6 the higher the probability should be.

Thanks.

Comment: It varies depending on how the probability decays as we go further away from $6$ - linearly, exponentially, etc.

Comment: Let's go with exponentially.

Comment: Also, if $P(6)=1$, obviously $P(x\vert x\neq 6)=0$

Comment: Whoa, I feel dumb now! What i really wanted to calculate is some assigned weight to each number in that interval. I'll use it as a "fuzz factor"  to define membership to a certain category.

Comment: There are so many distributions, you can linearly transform a beta distribution on that interval, you can truncate an exponential on that interval...

Comment: I'm not really a mathematician, I'm a biologist. I would appreciate if you pass me a function or explain to me with a simple example.

Comment: $$f(x)=\frac{e^{12-x}-1}{e^{6}-1},\ \ x\in[6,12]$$

Comment: I would appreciate if you explain how you derived it.

Comment: I did not _derive_ it. It's plain intuition.

Comment: I need to understand the intuition because sometimes i want to use different intervals, and different weights than 1 and 0.

Comment: @Abdelzaher try putting values from 6 to 12 for $x$ in that formula.

Comment: The simplest one is $\displaystyle 2 - {x \over 6}$.